# different types of user management on react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new to react native. I am trying to develop an application that uses firebase user authentication. But there is something I can think of. For example, 2 users have registered to my application but I want to show extra information to the first user according to a condition.

How can I separate these two?

Where exactly should I manage this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not super clear as to what issue you are trying to tackle so I apologize if I am inferring incorrectly.

I use MongoDB personally with a Node/Express backend for user data and haven't used Firebase myself but I'm sure you can do the same things with it.  I'll be speaking in Mongo terminology but again I'm sure you can do the same with Firebase and at the least this will give a good idea of the thought process.

I have a `UserSchema` that holds all the user information.  When logged in the client app would get this information to be used on the frontend after authentication.

Assuming you are only displaying "extra" information that doesn't need additional privilege you can just pull in the users data stored in firebase and handle the display of this extra info with logic on your frontend client.

If its extra privilege you need to setup firebase to look at the user data that is authenticating and only serve back information if they have the proper privileges.

Also important to note, you should ensure that when you are updating user information from client -> firebase backend you should ensure that you can only update specific user fields via read/write authentication on firebase.

Hope this gives a little better idea on how this process might look.  I'll let someone who has used firebase specifically add tech specifics.

Comment: thanx for your comment.ı understood.